# How can I render all the frames and not 1 frame at a time

Tags: animation

I am trying to render my intro on Blender but when I render it it only renders 1 frame at a time. Help? I need it to auto-render

Comment: What are you trying to render? An animation?

Comment: pressing F12 renders only the current frame, CTRL+F12 the whole sequence. Also check output settings/encoding, before.

Comment: I think rendering each frame one by one is the normal process

Comment: If you wish to render all frames, but each as single image, you can render as animation, setting an image format as output (eg: png), you'll find an image for each frame in the output folder (named in sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Use the render animation button found in the render context of the properties editor (or Ctrl-F12).

If you are trying to create a video the best practice is to take those rendered images and add them to the video sequence editor as an image strip and then change the render settings to whatever video output you'd like and render the animation again.